# how to add code more in react to hide and show pages when I click again

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rxjs, react-hooks, show-hide

I am messing around with React.js for the first time and cannot  show or hide pages  when I click button and outside click. I am not loading any other library to the page, so I am looking for some more code to using . This is what I have so far. I would like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtHYo.jpg)

Comment: your code should work, you don't see any components ?

Comment: You need a click handler on the button (like in Alpovka's answer) and use that variable to conditionally render different bits of markup.  So, if pageFlag === true, you render some JSX.... if not, you don't.  That is how you show/hide.

Comment: please so me codding

Answer (score 1):

U can do something like this maybe

```
const [pageFlag, setPage] = useState(false) // default value is false
onClick={() => setPage(!pageFlag)}  // toggle
```

Comment: If your state is dependent on the previous state then its a good practice to use function inside your state updater . `setPage(prevPageFlag => !prevPageFlag)`